Recycler view with live data items click not working properly
package com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.fragments


import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.LocationService
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.MainViewModel
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.R
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.adapters.LocationAdapter
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.LocationData
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.User


class HomeFragment : Fragment(), LocationAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var userLocationListAdapter: LocationAdapter
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val navController by lazy { findNavController() }
    private var userId = ""


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        viewModel.currentUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { currentUser ->
            if (currentUser != null) {
                val serviceIntent = Intent(requireContext(), LocationService::class.java)
                serviceIntent.putExtra("userId", currentUser.username)
                requireContext().startService(serviceIntent)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        requireContext().stopService(Intent(requireContext(), LocationService::class.java))

    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val locationRecycler = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.location_recycler)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        locationRecycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
        viewModel.currentUser()
        binding.usernameLayout.setOnClickListener {
            showUserListPopup()
        }
        viewModel.currentUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            viewModel.currentUser()
            if (it != null) {
                bindViewData(it)
                it.username?.let { it1 ->
                    userId = it1
                    viewModel.getLocationOfUser(it1)
                }
            }
        }
        userLocationListAdapter = LocationAdapter(emptyList() , this)
        locationRecycler.adapter = userLocationListAdapter

        viewModel.usersLocationLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { locationData ->
            userLocationListAdapter.updateData(locationData)
        }

    }

    private fun bindViewData(currentUser: User) {
        binding.usernameText.text = currentUser.username
        binding.title2.text = getString(R.string.location_log, currentUser.username)
    }

    private fun showUserListPopup() {
        val userListDialog = UserListDialogFragment()
        userListDialog.show(childFragmentManager, "UserListDialog")
    }

    override fun onItemClick(location : LocationData) {
        binding.progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("id", location.id)
        bundle.putString("userId", location.userId)
        bundle.putDouble("latitude", location.latitude)
        bundle.putDouble("longitude", location.longitude)
        bundle.putString("timestamp", location.timestamp)
        Log.d("TAG", "onItemClick: works")
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_mapsFragment, bundle)
        Log.d("TAG", "onItemClick: works2")
    }



}

This is the fragment class i use to to start the service and update the recycler view of the users location data but the item click of the list doesn't work properly and only work after 3 or 4 times of clicking...
package com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.LocationData
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.R

class LocationAdapter(
    private var locations: List<LocationData>,
    private var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(location: LocationData)
    }
    fun updateData(updatedLocationData: List<LocationData>) {
        locations = updatedLocationData
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.location_log_item, parent, false)
        return LocationViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val location = locations[position]
        holder.bind(location)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return locations.size
    }

    inner class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val locationNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name)
        private val cityNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_name)
        private val timeStampTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_stamp)
        private val viewButton: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewButton)
        private val locationLayout: RelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.overlay)

        fun bind(location: LocationData) {
            locationNameTextView.text = location.latitude.toString()
            cityNameTextView.text = location.longitude.toString()
            timeStampTextView.text = location.timestamp
            viewButton.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(location)
            }
            locationLayout.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(location)
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the adapter class I use...I tried everything i could but the problem still persists...I also update or get data from database in viewmodel.scope which is not in main thread...So I am unable to solve the problem...
package com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay

import android.location.Location
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.LocationData
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.Otp
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.RealmApplication
import com.kttelematicsolutions.routeplay.realmClasses.User
import io.realm.kotlin.UpdatePolicy
import io.realm.kotlin.delete
import io.realm.kotlin.ext.query
import io.realm.kotlin.query.RealmResults
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val realm = RealmApplication.realm
    private val _usersLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
    val usersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>> = _usersLiveData
    private val _currentUser = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val currentUser : LiveData<User> = _currentUser
    private val _usersLocationLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<LocationData>>()
    val usersLocationLiveData: LiveData<List<LocationData>> = _usersLocationLiveData
    fun addUser(
        email : String ,
        username : String ,
        password : String ,
        otp : String
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            realm.write {
                val user = User().apply {
                    this.username = username
                    this.email = email
                    this.password = password
                }
                copyToRealm(user , updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                val generateOtp = Otp().apply {
                    this.code = otp
                    this.id = user.email.toString()
                }
                copyToRealm(generateOtp , updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
            }
        }
    }

    fun verifyOtp(
        enteredOtp : String ,
        email : String ,
        callback : (success : Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val otpObject = realm.query<Otp>("id == $0" , email).find().first()
                if (otpObject.code == enteredOtp) {
                    realm.write {
                        this.delete<Otp>() // Delete the used OTP
                    }
                    callback(true)
                    realm.query<User>("email == $0", email).find().first().also {
                        realm.writeBlocking {
                            findLatest(it)?.isLoggedIn = true
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    callback(false)
                }
            } catch (exception : Exception) {
                Log.e("OtpViewModel" , "Error verifying user: ${exception.message}")
            }

        }
    }

    fun loginUser(email : String, password : String, otp : String, callback : (success : Boolean) -> Unit){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val userObject = realm.query<User>("email == $0 AND password == $1", email, password).find().first()
                if(userObject.isLoggedIn){
                    val generateOtp = Otp().apply {
                        this.code = otp
                        this.id = email
                    }
                    realm.write {
                        copyToRealm(generateOtp , updatePolicy = UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                    }
                    realm.query<User>("email == $0", email).find().first().also {
                        realm.writeBlocking {
                            findLatest(it)?.isLoggedIn = true
                            findLatest(it)?.currentUser = true
                        }

                    }
                    callback(true)
                }else{
                    callback(false)
                }
            }catch (exception : Exception){
                callback(false)
                Log.e("LoginViewModel" , "User Login Failed: ${exception.message}")
            }
        }
    }
    fun checkUserAlreadyExists(email: String, username: String, callback : (success : Boolean) -> Unit){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                realm.query<User>("email == $0 OR username == $1", email, username).find().first()
                callback(true)
            }catch (exception : Exception){
                callback(false)
                Log.e("SignupViewModel" , "User not exists: ${exception.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun setCurrentUser(selectedUser: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                realm.query<User>("email == $0", selectedUser).find().first().also {
                    realm.writeBlocking {
                        findLatest(it)?.currentUser = true
                    }
                    Log.d("SignupViewModel" , "User updated: Done")
                }
                val otherUsers = realm.query<User>("email != $0", selectedUser)
                for (user in otherUsers.find()) {
                    realm.write{
                        findLatest(user)?.currentUser = false
                    }
                }
                Log.d("SignupViewModel" , "Other User update: Done")
            }catch (exception : Exception){
                Log.e("SignupViewModel" , "User not exists: ${exception.message}")
            }

        }
    }
    fun getAllUsers() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val userResults: RealmResults<User> = realm.query<User>().find()
            val users = userResults.toList()
            _usersLiveData.postValue(users)
        }
    }
    fun currentUser(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val currentUserResult = realm.query<User>("currentUser==$0", true).find().first()
                _currentUser.postValue(currentUserResult)
            }catch (exception : Exception){
                Log.e("HomeViewModel" , "User not found: ${exception.message}")
            }

        }

    }
    fun saveLocationDataToRealm(userId: String, locationResult: Location, timestamp: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            realm.write {
                val locationData = LocationData().apply {
                    this.userId = userId
                    this.latitude = locationResult.latitude
                    this.longitude = locationResult.longitude
                    this.timestamp = timestamp
                }
                copyToRealm(locationData, UpdatePolicy.ALL)
                Log.e("HomeViewModel" , "User location: $locationData")
            }
        }
    }
    fun getLocationOfUser(userId: String){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            try {
                val currentUserLocationResult = realm.query<LocationData>("userId==$0", userId).find().toList()
                _usersLocationLiveData.postValue(currentUserLocationResult)
            }catch (exception: Exception){
                Log.e("HomeViewModel" , "User location not found: ${exception.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun getPreviousLocations(userId: String, currentLocationId: String): LiveData<List<LocationData>> {
        val previousLocationsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<LocationData>>()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val previousLocationsResult = realm.query<LocationData>("userId == $0 AND id <= $1", userId, currentLocationId).find()

                previousLocationsLiveData.postValue(previousLocationsResult)
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Log.e("MainViewModel", "Error retrieving previous locations: ${exception.message}")
            }
        }
        return previousLocationsLiveData
    }

}

And this is my view model class I use for further reference.
I would like the recycler view item to perform the click right away and not after 3 or 4 clicks...Please if anybody could solve, it would be of great help.

This looks correct to me. I suspect the problem is in your ViewModel.

Is that so, I included the view model code too for your reference. Can You take a look at it and give me your suggestion on what may cause the problem.
